# How does web forms be processed by the web server?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am learning flask through the book *Flask Web Development*. I am confused about how web forms be processed by the web server. More concretely, how POSt request be processed in the web server?

Here is code snippet for generating response to the main index request:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    name = None
    form = NameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        form.name.data = ''
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, name=name)
```

In my opinion, when the client visit the main index for the first time, flask app will receive a GET request. This GET request will be processed by the `index` view function. `form` will be constructed from `NameForm()`, and it will be empty at that time. So `form.validate_on_submit()` will return false.

Then, when user submits the form with data through a POST request, it will also be processed by the `index` view function. So another `form` will be constructed from `NameFrom()`, and I think it will be empty too, which make `form.validate_on_submit()` still return false.

Obviously, my thinking is wrong.

My question is: how does `form.validate_on_submit()` evaluated to be true when user submit the form through a POST?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Flask the current request context can be obtained from `flask.request`. The request object includes the current method and POST variables (along with headers/cookies/path etc from the HTTP protocol).

When a call is made to `form.validate_on_submit()` this method uses the current request object to first check if the request method is POST before extracting and validating the POST variables.

Comment: But when the server process the POST request, it constructs a new, empty `form` from `form = NameForm()`, doesn't it?

Comment: @Bicheng Looking at the Flask-WT-Forms source code shows that it constructs a new form with an Auto placeholder, this is then handled internally to load the correct data. See https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/73e8c586b89c14a98312d8b48afe23e97a513b57/flask_wtf/form.py#L54